# How to have service layer in loopback just like in other popular mvc frameworks?

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs

I have started building an application in sailsjs but I  decided to move it to loopback. From a j2ee/spring mvc background I was quickly up and running with sailsjs with some of my business logic  in the api/service.

Unfortunatly I have not found a way to create those services on loopback. I am not talking about remote method. These services are not really tied to any model, they are on a layer above models. I have tried creating the following at server/service/DataModelService.js

```
module.exports = {
   testMethod: function(){
      return "Hello joseph"
   },
   testAnotherMethod: function(req,res){
       //lots of other processing etc. Calling other services etc
      res.send("something")
   }
}
```

Created server/boo/routes.js with this following

```
module.exports = function(app){
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    res.send(DataModelService.testMethod());
});

}
```

but quickly got this reference error:

```
DataModelService is not defined
at /media/joseph/Data/Personal/tutorials/testingloopback/server /boot/routes.js:3:18
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/media/joseph/Data/Personal/tutorials/testingloopback/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/media/joseph/Data/Personal/tutorials/testingloopback/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/media/joseph/Data/Personal/tutorials/testingloopback/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/media/joseph/Data/Personal/tutorials/testingloopback/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /media/joseph/Data/Personal/tutorials/testingloopback/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (/media/joseph/Data/Personal/tutorials/testingloopback/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/media/joseph/Data/Personal/tutorials/testingloopback/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at cors (/media/joseph/Data/Personal/tutorials/testingloopback/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:178:7)
at /media/joseph/Data/Personal/tutorials/testingloopback/node_modules /cors/lib/index.js:228:17
```

Can anyone show the right way of doing this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try operation hooks? https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks

Comment: Hello @ViniciusZaramella thanks for your suggestion. It looks to me that everything is kind of tied to the Model in Loopback. Isn't there a place to independently of a model perform some sort of operaionts, functions or business logic?

Comment: It depends what you want to do. You could use some logic in middlewares too.

Comment: You should be able to do everything you can do with node/express when using loopback. But inside the framework almost everything is model related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `require` the module you're trying to access. Try this:

```
// server/boot/routes.js
var DataModelService = require('../service/DataModelService.js');

module.exports = function(app){
  app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    res.send(DataModelService.testMethod());
  });
};
```

Without the `require()` call the variable is undefined. You can `require` this service (which is just a plain Node module) in any file in your application this way.

Comment: Hello Thanks for the info. Looks like express . Isn't there a way to load a whole folder?

Comment: LoopBack is based on Express, it uses it under the covers. But the `require()` method is not Express, that is [core to Node itself](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require). You cannot load more than one file at a time with `require`, however, you can specify a directory with a `package.json` file in it and Node will look for the `main` entry in that JSON file and load that file. That file could then `require()` lots of other files.