# Best Practice : Service Layer in Loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, service-layer

I am building an application in loopback and wondering how to build a service layer with an API which is not related to any model. Here is my scenario.

I have a two models `User`, `Game`, `UserGames`. `UserGames` is a `many-to-many` relation and stores the score of users in different games. I want to provide an API for `weeklyLeaderboard` but I don't want it to be a `Remote Method` for any of the my models as it doesn't fit the RESTful API guidelines.

The only way I can find to implement right now is to create a service `common/service/weeklyLeaderboard.js` and a `route` in `server/boot/routes.js` which accesses this service. In that case, I would have to re-arrange the middlewares in my `middleware.json` to have non remote-method end-points treated in the same way as remote methods and have access to the currentContext.

Is there a better way to implement APIs which are not related to a specific model but access several data-access and business objects.

Comment: I had the same problem when I first used Loopback.JS after using Sails.JS. This link shows a sample of implementing service: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35117050/how-to-have-service-layer-in-loopback-just-like-in-other-popular-mvc-frameworks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am a co-author and an active maintainer of LoopBack.*

In our recently released LoopBack version 4, we have decoupled REST APIs from the database access. REST APIs are implemented by [Controller](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Controllers.html) classes, data structures are described by [Models](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Model.html) and database is accessed via [Repositories](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Repositories.html). This makes it easy to write a service layer that's decoupled from data-access details.

In LoopBack 3, I recommend to create a new model (e.g. `Leaderboard`) and treat it as a controller. There are two tricks needed to make it work:

- Inherit from `Model`, not the default `PersistedModel`. That way your controller-like model starts empty, with no (built-in) remote methods.
- Don't attach your controller-like model to any datasource. In `server/model-config.json`, set the `dataSource` entry of your new model to `null`.

Then you can define your `weeklyLeaderboard` endpoint as a regular [remote method](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html) and get all benefits offered by LoopBack, e.g. your new endpoint will be included in the generated Swagger spec and testable via API Explorer.

Comment: I'm still puzzled about the tiered architecture. Sure, you have different components that have separation of concerns. However, they are still inside a monolythinc application. I thought the layered architecture meant you could keep each layer in a different machine or container and make them speak to each other, but in my head I cannot imagine how could this work. Perhaps it could be done having one loopback app having a single datasource (Rest Connector) and a second one having the real connectors to the database? In that case we'd need to duplicate each model in both apps

Comment: Think about the Model-View-Controller pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller. In REST APIs, the "view" layer is provided by the framework (send the data as JSON response). Models and Controllers live in the same monolith and are used to organize the code in a cleaner way (separation of concerns).

Comment: Yeah I saw a slideshare describing it. I guess the connectors in turn could be considered the infrastructure layer because you don't interact with the persistence layer directly.